# <select> Default Value

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an issue where by I want to save a user input and then allow them to edit it later.

when i list the results for the edit their is no default.

```
<select id="edit_group" name="edit_group" class="form-control">
 <?php Types("") ?>
</select>
```

types function is

```
function Types($x){

global $mysqli;

    $type = " SELECT type FROM types ";

    if ($type_results = $mysqli->query($type)) {

        while ($row = $type_results->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("<option>%s</option>", $row["type"]);
        }

        $type_results->free();

        }

}
```

if anyone could point me in the right direction of how i could set the default value so its the one stored in the db, it would really help a beginner out. or better still point me in the right direction of documentation as my google searches have returned nothing but json and java options.

Comment: `if ($row['type'] == 'previously selected value') { add 'selected' attribute to option }`

Comment: Where in your code do you determine which one is stored in the db? You'll need to pass that value to your `Types` function in order to know which option should be marked as selected.

Comment: I have the value and can pass it over with ease but i cant think of how to make that value default

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use an argument `$x` of your `Types` function which as i guess is a selected value. Try to replace your function with this code:

```
function Types($x) {    
    global $mysqli;

    $type = " SELECT type FROM types ";

    if ($type_results = $mysqli->query($type)) {
        while ($row = $type_results->fetch_assoc()) {
            $selected = ($row["type"] == $x) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
            printf ("<option %s>%s</option>", $selected, $row["type"]);
        }

        $type_results->free();
    }    
}
```

and of course provide selected value to function `Types` in your html code.

Comment: You sir are a wizard! So grateful! my brain is boggled though 

 $selected = ($row["type"] == $x) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';

What is this line actually doing? Could you link me to some documentation on this?

Comment: It's a ternary operator (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). In short way it's equal to if ($row["type"] == $x) { $selected = 'selected="selected"'; } else { $selected = ''; } .

Comment: that is why my brain was boggled then! I knew it was an if or something simpler but could not find what it was called thanks again!